# How to resolve FileNotFound Exception in browser connection in android?

Tags: android, url, filenotfoundexception

I am trying download an image from through link Url in my app, but i am getting file not found exception in the response error. But when i copied the url and pasted in browser, the path contains the image, can anyone tel me how to resolve this error. Advance thanks.

My url path:

```
com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl:http://30.30.30.38:51749/Content/AdminUploads/close.png
```

Do i have to change the url type.

My code:

```
URL url = new URL(dwnload_file_path);
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

    //connect
    urlConnection.connect();

    //set the path where we want to save the file           
    File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); 
    //create a new file, to save the downloaded file 
    File file = new File(SDCardRoot,"downloaded_file.png");

    FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);

    //Stream used for reading the data from the internet
    InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

    //this is the total size of the file which we are downloading
    totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();
```

Stackflow:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-66292
Process:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
    at android.widget.Toast$TN.<init>(Toast.java:336)
    at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:100)
    at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:250)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: Can i see the stacktrace?

Comment: i have same my stack error can anyone fine me a solution.